# Sets what is it equal to

Tags: elementary-set-theory

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SxwV.jpg

Why is the answer D? I think the answer is B. How can it be empty - since we are removing the set A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify the grouping, the set in question is $$A \cap \left[(A \cup B \cup C) \setminus A\right].$$

Consider $(A \cup B \cup C) \setminus A$. In words, from $(A \cup B \cup C)$, we remove every element in $A$. Therefore, no element of $A$ is in $(A \cup B \cup C) \setminus A$. Therefore, $A$ and $(A \cup B \cup C) \setminus A$ have no elements in common. In set-theoretic terms, the sets $A$ and $(A \cup B \cup C) \setminus A$ are disjoint. The intersection of disjoint sets is empty, i.e., $$A \cap \left[(A \cup B \cup C) \setminus A\right] = \emptyset.$$

---

Alternatively, consider a more formal approach:
$$
  \begin{align*}
    A \cap \left[(A \cup B \cup C) \setminus A\right]
    & = A \cap \left[(A \cup B \cup C) \cap A^{\complement}\right] & \text{Def'n of Set Complement} \\
    & = \left[A \cap (A \cup B \cup C)\right] \cap A^{\complement} & \text{Intersection is Associative} \\
    & = A \cap A^{\complement} & \text{Intersection with Subset is Subset} \\
    & = \emptyset & \text{Intersection of Disjoint Sets is Empty}
  \end{align*}
$$

To justify the third line, note $A \subseteq (A \cup B \cup C)$. Therefore, as Ian pointed out in his comment, $A \cap (A \cup B \cup C) = A$. For a detailed proof, see [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_with_Subset_is_Subset).

Comment: So lets say: A = {1,2}, B = {3,4}, C = {4,5}

Then: A U B U C = {1,2,3,4,5}

(A U B U C) - A = {3,4,5} so by saying A ∩ {3,4,5} there is no elements in the set, thus its empty. Is my understanding correct or, do i miss something.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. You did not miss anything. =)

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in A\cap(A\cup B\cup C)\backslash A$, then $x\in A$ (because of the "$A\cap$") and $x\not\in A$ (because of the "$\backslash A$").  There can be no such $x$, so $A\cap(A\cup B\cup C)\backslash A=\emptyset$.